# Using Dictionary method to match data from two worksheets 17,500 rows takes 15 mins

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to speed up a way to refresh data. I import data to a worksheet called Dictionary. I then need to loop through rows 2 to 17,500 on Traffic Data worksheet. And based on a match in Column A . Add the data from the Dictionary file to the Traffic Data file. The code below works , but it is taking 15 mins to run on a high spec laptop. to loop through 17.500 rows of data in the Traffic Data worksheet. And 2492 rows in the Dictionary worksheet. There are fewer rows of data in the dictionary worksheet as there a duplicated values in the traffic file as rows are added each year. So there can be upto 8 rows of the same code in column A , each with a different year date. I cant work out why it is taking so long any help would be much appreciated

```
Sub CompareLists()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim RngList As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim dict As Worksheet
    Dim traffic As Worksheet

    Set RngList = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dict = Worksheets("Dictionary")
    Set traffic = Worksheets("Traffic Data")


    With RngList
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each Rng In dict.Range("A2", dict.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not .Exists(Rng.Value) Then .Add Rng.Value, Rng.row
        Next Rng



        For Each Rng In traffic.Range("A2", traffic.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If .Exists(Rng.Value) Then
                Rng.Offset(, 1) = dict.Range("B" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'Comp
                Rng.Offset(, 124) = dict.Range("C" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'Status
                Rng.Offset(, 125) = dict.Range("E" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'Trading Suspended
                Rng.Offset(, 126) = dict.Range("F" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'Trading End
                Rng.Offset(, 136) = dict.Range("G" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'area
                Rng.Offset(, 128) = dict.Range("D" & RngList(Rng.Value)) 'zone
                Else
                Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next Rng
    End With

    Set RngList = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
Application.Calculation = calcState
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = displayPageBreaksState
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use match function to match data and conditional formatting to highlight.

Comment: could you show me an example code please , i have tried so many methods to try and get it to work faster. Thanks

Comment: all i need is to update the data in the Traffic Data worksheet  file from the Dictionary sheet. by matching a code in column A

Comment: What you actually want to do? Can you show us you sample data and expected output result?

Comment: I have numeric id numbers in the worksheet called Traffic Data column A that I need to match with the updated data in the dictionary worksheet Column A. There are 17,500 rows of data to look at . When a match is found. Then from the matched row in the Dictionary worksheet needs to be copied to the Traffic Worksheet. There are 7 columns of data in the Dictionary Worksheet. And they need be copied to the relevant column. Dictionary Column B to Traffic Column B. Dictionary Column C to Traffic Column DU. Dictionary Column D to Traffic Column DY.

Comment: I wouldn't loop twice, and in addition of dictionary , i'd use an array to read the full sheet . Oh, and pleas dont call your sheet dictionary, it's confusing for the programer to read (Just call the variables Sh1 and Sh2). Also RngList is a dictionary, not a range, so call it DictList. And put Rng.value in a String variable in the 2nd loop, or it reads it 7 times for nothing (slow)

Comment: The second loop could use a `with rng`

Answer (score 0):

The .Value method that you call frequently is a bottleneck, also the formatting with .Interior.ColorIndex. Each cell access operation has overhead that makes it slow.  It is a bit more complex, but extremely faster, to read a range of cells to a 2-dimension array and then reference it, so long that all you need are values and not e.g. formats. values can be pasted back in the same way in one shot if needed.

I don't have your dataset to check how to optimize, but using an array for the dict, and one for columns A:G of traffic.

To test out the performance difference, below are 2 subs that will create a new worksheet, and do 1 simple assignment to the cell value of a 40k cell range. The code using value takes ~10s on my machine, the one with array ~0.1s.

As for the .Interior.ColorIndex call, you may make it faster by filtering and the applying the style in one shot for visible cells but it's much more complicated and I do not have data how you could set up the filter, you should already see a great improvement in performance this way.

```
Sub testValue()
    'setting up same conditions
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim t As Single
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "start"
    ws.Range("T2000").Value = "end" ' 40000 cells will be considered used
    t = Timer
    Set r = ws.UsedRange

    ' PART OF INTEREST START
    For Each cell In r
        cell.Value = "x"
    Next cell
    ' PART OF INTEREST END

    MsgBox (Timer - t)
    ws.Activate
    'reset setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
    Application.Calculation = calcState
    Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
End Sub

Sub testArray()
    'setting up same conditions
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim t As Single
    Dim r As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "start"
    ws.Range("T2000").Value = "end" ' 40000 cells will be considered used
    t = Timer
    Set r = ws.UsedRange

    ' PART OF INTEREST START
    arr = r.Value
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(i, j) = "x"
        Next j
    Next i
    r.Value = arr
    ' PART OF INTEREST END

    MsgBox (Timer - t)
    ws.Activate
    'reset setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState
    Application.Calculation = calcState
    Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
End Sub
```